# On Google App Engine - PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Tags: php, postgresql, google-app-engine

I'm trying make a local call to my PostgreSQL instance from PHP using Google Cloud Platform.
PHP is deployed on the same project as the PostgreSQL.

My call is:

```
$conn_string = "host='/cloudsql/<MY_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>' dbname='<MY_DB>' user='<USER>' password='<PASSWORD>' options='--client_encoding=utf8'";
$db = pg_connect($conn_string);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect() in ...
```

In **phpinfo** method I can see the following:

[image]

When adding PostgreSQL extensions to php.ini, I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/base/php_experiment_runtime/modules/pgsql.so' - /base/php_experiment_runtime/modules/pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/base/php_experiment_runtime/modules/php_pgsql.so' - /base/php_experiment_runtime/modules/php_pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

My php.ini:

```
extension=pgsql.so
extension=php_pgsql.so
```

It seems like these extensions are not installed on the App Engine by default, or something of this sort.
Since it is an App Engine it has no VM instance, and I don't see how I can connect and install the modules myself.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use the PDO class instead, as suggested:

```
$pdo = new PDO('pgsql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<MY_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>;dbname=<MY_DB>', $username, $password)
```

The error I get is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in ...
```

Again, I don't see a way in the App Engine to install the packages manually.

Comment: What is your PHP version ? Seems you use a pg_connect() function that is no more recommanded for PHP, replace it with a PDO connection to establish communication between your app and your PostgreSQL server

Comment: Hi I'm using PHP 5.5.38. I'm using a PHP class to connect, and that kind of change would be significantly complicated. I'm still looking for a way to make it work with this if possible. But I will try your suggestion anyways on a shorter scale to see if that could work.

Comment: 2 years ago and no answer. Hello @RoeiFinkelstein, did you managed to get a solution?